# How do I get the display name for an IdentityReference object?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Given the `IdentityReference` objects returned by `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`, how do I find the display/friendly name of the given group?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`identityReference.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value` should do it.

Comment: Perfect, this did the trick, I was trying `new NTAccount(identityReference.Value)` :)

Answer (score 0):

try for the Groups:

```
PrincipalContext PC = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

foreach (var G in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups )
{
string DisplayN = Principal.FindByIdentity (PC, IdentityType.Sid, G.ToString() ).DisplayName;
}
```

try for the User:

```
string DisplayN = Principal.FindByIdentity (new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine), IdentityType.Sid, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString() ).DisplayName;
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx

Comment: This will only partially work for given groups, it does not seem to return all groups a user belongs to in active directory. I changed the `ContextType.Machine` to `ContextType.Machine | ContextType.Domain`.

Comment: @BrettRyan you can't use `ContextType.Machine | ContextType.Domain` since the `ContextType` is not a bitmask enum, and doesn't have `Flags` attribute.
Also because `ContextType.Machine | ContextType.Domain` is equal to `ContextType.Domain`.